# How to arrange item in recyclerview?

Tags: android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I am using GridLayoutManager in RecyclerView. My item are arranged as

```
a1 b1 c1
a2 b2 c2
a3 b3 c3
```

but I want to arrange like

```
a1 a2 a3
b1 b2 b3
c1 c2 c3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As My point of view, You have set orientation and reverselayout in GridLayoutManager, remove both of them and try like that

```
new GridLayoutManager(this, 3, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true);
```

use it

```
new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
```